# regex word boundary will not work with diacritic characters

Tags: javascript, regex, word-boundary

Assuming you have the following input to check against:

```
lorem ipsüm dolor ipsum dolor
```

and the following JavaScript RegExp:

```
/(\bips[uü]\b)/gmi
```

What I expect is that nothing will be found as I am searching for a match, either "ipsu" or "ipsü" but with a word boundary. But the word "ipsü" will be matched, even if there is the character "m" at the end and not a word boundary. I don't understand the reason.

Does anyone know the reason?

See this example:

https://regex101.com/r/kM0zW7/2

Comment: `ü` in JS is not considered a word character (cannot be matched with `\w`). Use `\bips[uü](?=\s|$)`. Or create a custum word boundary using a character class.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you. Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is also true for the start of a regex?

Comment: For a start of regex, you can use `(?:^|\s)ips[uü](?=\s|$)`.

Comment: I think `ü` is extended ascii and considered a word.  So `\w\b` won't match `ü`m. But I don't know if JS will do unicode word's.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That regex will also match a blank before "ipsu", see https://regex101.com/r/zZ0nH6/1

Comment: JS is a crippled engine for many reasons. There is a desire for MS to fix it since they probably wrote the original spec for it.

Comment: @julmot: That is not a problem. One can always use capturing groups. [`(?:^|\s)(ips[uü])(?=\s|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/kM0zW7/4)